# How to show different value returned from function for each rendered element from API in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, render

I'm making a bookstore shopping cart. I'm using Google books API, but since there are no prices available, I made a function that creates random values for every book retrieved from the API.
Is there any way for me to render different value for each book? It renders only one value, which is the last returned value for every book.

Please note that this is just the relevant part of the code:

```
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = { books: [] };
  }

  // books are rendered on search
  onTermSubmit = (term) => {
    axios
      .get(`https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=${term}${KEY}`)
      .then((res) => {
        this.setState({ books: res.data.items });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  render() {
    const { books } = this.state;
    const someArr = [];
    let bookPrice = '';

    function getRandomPrices(min, max) {
      return Number((Math.random() * (max - min) + min).toFixed(2));
    }

    // for each book
    books.forEach((book) => {
      // get random price
      bookPrice = getRandomPrices(2, 25);
      // and assign it as a book price
      someArr.push(bookPrice);
    });

    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {books.map((book) => (
            <li key={book.id}>
              <div className="row">
                <div className="col">
                  <h4>{book.volumeInfo.title}</h4>
                  <h6>author: {book.volumeInfo.authors}</h6>
                  <p>
                    <small>pages: {book.volumeInfo.pageCount}</small>
                  </p>
                  //HAVE NO IDEA HOW TO RENDER DIFFERENT PRICES, IT RENDERS SAME VALUE FOR EACH BOOK
                      price: 
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Add a price property to each book object and assign it a value then render `{book.price}`. Rather than generate prices in `render()` could do that to original array from axios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @charlietfl rightly said, the random prices should be generated right where the `books` array is being set to state.

First I made your helper function a class method:

```
  getRandomPrices = (min, max) => {
    return Number((Math.random() * (max - min) + min).toFixed(2));
  };
```

Then I instantiated the same, generated a random `price` and mapped a new modified array of books, that contains your response and the random price:

```
  onTermSubmit = (term) => {
    axios
      .get(`https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=${term}${KEY}`)
      .then((res) => {
        let books = res.data.items;
        books = books.map((bookObj) => ({
          ...bookObj,
          price: this.getRandomPrices(2, 25)
        }));
        this.setState({ books });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
```

And removed all the redundant code from the `render`:

```
  render() {
    // const { books } = this.state;
    // const someArr = [];
    // let bookPrice = '';

    // // for each book
    // books.forEach((book) => {
    //   // get random price
    //   bookPrice = getRandomPrices(2, 25);
    //   // and assign it as a book price
    //   someArr.push(bookPrice);
    // });

    return (
```

Comment: Yup, this works..Thanks a lot, @charlietfl you too.. Spent days trying to figure out solution on my own, this was my last resort.. 
Thanks fellow coders :D